# extending laravel blade comming to top

Tags: laravel

i am an absolute beginner in **laravel** i have a basic structure for now, there is an **app** template which contains the structure of the view i.e

```
head

navbar

@yield("content")

footer
```

now the structure is working fine now for some specific pages i have to include google map the map blade is placed inside `includes/map.blade.php` this is my index blade

```
    @extends("app")

    @section("content")

    the content goes here

    @extends("includes.map")

    @endsection
```

basically after the content i want to put the map so that it comes above footer but somehow whenever i try to extent it it always comes at the top

Comment: Instead of `@extends("includes.map")` use `@include("includes.map")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include the map then it should be `@include` ([doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#including-sub-views)):

```
@extends("app")

@section("content")

the content goes here

@include("includes.map")

@endsection
```

Comment: perfect buddy i am new to laravel so dont know the conventions properly right now! keep up the good work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use two extends.
Instead of `@extends(&quot;includes.map&quot;)` use `@include(&quot;includes.map&quot;)`